# Date Conversion Failed

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to convert an NVARChar to a date field using the following code.

```
Select
Convert(Date, In_Date, 105) as ReportDate
From
Employees
```

I get the following error:
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any suggestions- I only need date, not time.

Thanks,

Comment: Change the format (e.g. not 105) or fix the junk data? Possibly you have instances of, say, '2017-07-01' or something in there and because 105 is dd-mm-yyyy it doesn't recognise the 2017th of July in year 1 as a valid date format.

Comment: Thanks had to use 1 not even 101.  Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to use format 1 not 103.  Thanks for the advice ZLK